# ASP.NET MVC URL Parameters Double Escaped?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, url-parameters

I've got a text area that contains HTML.  I expect the content to be escaped when posted to the controller method but I'm finding it is escaped twice.  What could possibly cause this?  See the example below:

Pulled from request:

```
&amp;lt;b&amp;gt;test&amp;lt;/b&amp;gt;
```

WebUtility.HtmlDecode 1st time:

```
&lt;b&gt;test&lt;/b&gt;
```

WebUtility.HtmlDecode 2nd time:

```
<b>test</b>
```

I'm no expert when it comes to web development but I've got about 2 years of experience.  This is the first time I've seen anything like this.  I've attempted adding the following sections to my `Web.config` with no luck:

```
<pages validateRequest="false" />
<httpRuntime requestValidationMode="2.0" /


<security>
  <requestFiltering allowDoubleEscaping="false" />
</security>
```

Please let me know if I can provide more information.

Comment: Have you seen [Allow user to input HTML in asp.net MVC](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3621272/allow-user-to-input-html-in-asp-net-mvc)?

Comment: I have, but I have not had luck with those solutions.  The string pulled from the request is still twice escaped.

Comment: What does the view/viewmodel/controller look like?

Comment: It's a standard ASP.net view with a kendoEditor, the model is all over the place (web api calls via Jquery) and the controller is a WebAPI controller.  I found the solution however.  It turns out the kendoEditor was escaping the characters, then ASP.net was doing it's standard escpaing as well.  Thanks for the help though!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out the problem lay in the `textarea` itself.  In the view it was just a standard `textarea`, but in Javascript `document.Ready` was then made to be a `kendoEditor`.  The `kendoEditor` was encoding the HTML first, then ASP.net was applying its standard encoding as well.  Setting the attribute `encoded` equal to false fixed the issue:

```
    $("#editor").kendoEditor({
        encoded: false
    });
```

**Update:**
I found later that setting the `encoded` attribute to false would introduce another problem.  On submit I received a "A potentially dangerous Request.Form value was detected from the client" error when using formatting tools from the built-in `KendoEditor` toolbar.    My solution was to double-decode the posted request:

```
WebUtility.HtmlDecode(WebUtility.HtmlDecode(Request["value"]));
```