# How do I have dangerous request return a validation error instead of throwing an exception?

Tags: .net, validation, asp.net-mvc-4

So MVC is throwing a dangerous request error when submitting a form value containing markup (e.g. `<http://www.stuff.com>`). Is it possible to have the form validation still work but return a Model state error instead of throwing a dangerous request exception?

Comment: did you mean to have the example show up as `<http://www.stuff.com>` ?

Answer (score 1):

there are a few options, you could use the attribute `[AllowHtml]` and then check for html server side, and then add model state errors and return, or you could also use a hidden field, and encode it so that the `<` becomes `&lt;` a few other options are listed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/81991/a-potentially-dangerous-request-form-value-was-detected-from-the-client) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3621272/allow-user-to-input-html-in-asp-net-mvc) on the validation part.

I would suggest looking at `HtmlEncode`, as there may or may not be a legitimate case for someone to write < or > in a field.