# Validation Errors with string contain html tags - MVC

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc, razor

I keep getting an error saying "A potentially dangerous Request.Form value was detected from the client". It is because I have html styling tags within the string which I use to display the string within a text area. I need a way to turn off the validation of this item because it keeps displaying the potentially dangerous page. I have found some other sources but I have not had any success yet.

I have tried:

1.) Adding `[ValidationInput(false)]` at the top of the Action and I was still getting the potentially harmul page.

2.) Adding the `<pages validateRequest="false"></pages>` and `<httpruntime requestValidationMode = "2.0"></httpruntime>`in the Web.config but I was gettting a HTTP Error 500.19 - Internal Server Error. With the error on `<pages validateRequest="false"></pages>`

Is there any way to get past this error?

Here is my model:

```
public partial class AP_Tasks
    {
        public int TaskID { get; set; }
        public Nullable<System.DateTime> TaskDate { get; set; }
        public string TaskType { get; set; }
        public string AssignedBy { get; set; }
        public string AssignedTo { get; set; }
        public string CC { get; set; }
        public string Whse { get; set; }
        public string PO { get; set; }
        public string FreightNo { get; set; }
        public string VendName { get; set; }
        public Nullable<System.DateTime> ReqCompDate { get; set; }
        public Nullable<System.DateTime> DueDate { get; set; }
        public Nullable<System.DateTime> CompDate { get; set; }

        public string Notes { get; set; }
        public Nullable<System.DateTime> InvDate { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> CoNo { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> NoteCnt { get; set; }
    }
```

I believe that Notes is the issue. It is the string that containes the HTML tags.

Comment: What was the `505` error?

Comment: Sorry, it was 500.19 error. I changed my post

Comment: from the [second answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3621272/allow-user-to-input-html-in-asp-net-mvc) => `What about [AllowHtml] attribute above property?`

Comment: Yep, you just need to add `[AllowHtml]` to the property.

Comment: Thank you guys. Can you please make answer to i can mark it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set it on the property level via the [[AllowHtml](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.allowhtmlattribute%28v=vs.118%29.aspx)] attribute