# Avoid security risks when using RTE to send formatting?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, nicedit

I'm using NicEdit for formatting texts in my ASP.NET MVC project, when I save the text, I get this error:

> A potentially dangerous Request.Form value was detected from the
>   client (`Body="<font size="6">text` ...").

I understand the risk to post raw HTML, but is there a way to allow NicEdit to work without violating security rules?

**Edit:**

I put the attribute:`[ValidateInput(false)]` on the actions and used `Html.Raw()` in the views. Not sure if this is the best solution to take!

Comment: Apply `[AllowHtml]` to the property of your model rather than `[ValidateInput(false)]` - [ValidateInput(false) vs AllowHtml](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25630141/validateinputfalse-vs-allowhtml)