# Umbraco 7 MVC - Request.Form gives me dangerous request error

Tags: asp.net-mvc, umbraco

In the shopping basket of my site, i need to allow a form POST of XML coming from a third-party service.

The possible solutions i can find is for webforms and < Umbraco 7.
I'm aware that you can disable page validation entirely, but that's not an option in my case.

Does someone know the equivalent way of using the control `<umbraco:DisableRequestValidation runat="server"/>` in MVC?

Answer (score 3):

for security reason, I would suggest try use `[AllowHtml]` on property which would contain the xml content

so say you viewmodel has property call `ThirdPartyContent` which will have xml:

```
    public class VM
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        [AllowHtml]
        public string ThirdPartyContent { get; set; }
    }
```

this implicit state which property you are aware will contain potential malicious content (which is angle bracket)

`[ValidateInput(false)]` does the trick but will assume all property may contain xml content which may not be good thing

more info checkout this SO answer which say the difference between `[AllowHtml]` and `[ValidateInput(false)]`

[ValidateInput(false) vs AllowHtml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25630141/validateinputfalse-vs-allowhtml)

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer to my own question.
It's possible to set the `[ValidateInput(false)]` annotation on RenderMvcControllers. So you can do it per document type which is kinda nice.

I'll leave the answer here in case someone else needs to do the same thing.