# HttpRequestValidationException is thrown despite having [AllowHtml] attribute

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, request-validation

I have the following view model, which accepts a password change value. As such, it should accept special characters, including characters that trigger the `HttpRequestValidationException` - '<' and '>'. So I added the `[AllowHtml]` attribute on the appropriate properties:

```cs
    public class ChangePasswordModel
    {
        public bool ShowPassword { get; set; }

        public string UserMessage { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [StringLength(int.MaxValue, ErrorMessage = "The {0} must be at least {2} characters long.", MinimumLength = 8)]
        [ValidPassword]
        [DataType(DataType.Password)]
        [Display(Name = "Password")]
        [AllowHtml]
        public string Password { get; set; }

        [DataType(DataType.Password)]
        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Confirm password")]
        [Compare(nameof(Password), ErrorMessage = "The {1} and {0} do not match.")]
        [AllowHtml]
        public string ConfirmPassword { get; set; }
    }
```

Here `ShowPassword` and `UserMessage` are set on the server and used in the view.

When I enter a password such as "<Script/>1234" it all works fine, the model validates, the action is executed, the `ViewResult` is executed, and then, somewhere between the `ViewResult` and the client, an `HttpRequestValidationException` is thrown with this stack trace:

```
Microsoft.AspNet.TelemetryCorrelation.TelemetryCorrelationHttpModule.OnExecuteRequestStep(HttpContextBase context, Action step)
Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Web.ApplicationInsightsHttpModule.OnExecuteRequestStep(HttpContextBase context, Action step)
```

I'm catching it in Global.asax.cs in the `Application_Error` event, where it's too late to return any useful information to the user except a generic message.

What I tried:

- I have a global `HandleErrorAttribute` where I detect an `HttpRequestValidationException` and return it to the user as a validation message in the view. This works fine with other models and views when the user enters HTML where he is not allowed to, but in this case the attribute's `OnException` override is not triggered.
- I decorated the specific action with the above attribute
- I implemented `IResultFilter` in the above attribute and overrode the `OnResultExecuted`, to test if the exception is thrown after the view execution. The `ResultExecutedContext.Exception` property was **null**.
- I overrode the `BindModel` method of the `DefaultModelBinder` just to see if it throws an exception, but it doesn't.
- I upgraded Application Insights, mentioned in the stack trace, to the latest version, from  2.16 to 2.20.
- This model has its attributes directly on the properties. I tried moving them to a metadata type, using the `[MetadataType]` attribute. It worked, except that the exception was still thrown.

At this point, I'm out of ideas as to **why the exception is thrown, and how to prevent or catch it**. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It appears, that you just need to use the **"[ValidateInput(false)]"** attribute instead of the **"[AllowHtml]"** one if you need to allow the script(s) tag(s). Check out the [ValidateInput(false) vs AllowHtml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25630141) thread for more information.

Comment: I tried that. Amazingly, it didn't work. `ValidateInput` prevents request validation **before** the action, but in this case something is performing request validation **after** the action and the ActionResult execution.

Comment: The only think that worked to disable request validation was setting `<httpRuntime requestValidationMode="0.0" />`, which of course disables it for the entire application.