# How to suppress the 'potentially dangerous requestform value' in MVC with a raw httppost form

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, forms, asp.net-mvc-4

I am using a standard MVC Controller to receive requests in raw httppost form fashion.  No model objects. 
I want to suppress the check for potentially dangerous request form value on one of the form fields being passed.  I expect HTML/XML to be entered into this field.

When I access the the HttpContext.Request.Form["XMLCode"] I don't care that it could be potentially dangerous.  How can I suppress this validation?

Do I need to change this to an APIController instead of standard MVC Controller?

I have already tried adding the [ValidateInput(false)] but that did not work.

Comment: `[AllowHtml]` [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3621272/allow-user-to-input-html-in-asp-net-mvc](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3621272/allow-user-to-input-html-in-asp-net-mvc)

Comment: I am not using a model.  I am taking in a raw HttpPost form.  I get the values passed like HttpContext.Request.Form["valuename"].  If there is a method to create a model from form values I would look at that too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
var xmlString = Request.Unvalidated.Form["XMLCode"];
```

It looks like the Request validation is triggered when you try to access `Request.Form`. The way around this is to access the values through the `Request.Unvalidated` property.

From [the docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequestbase.unvalidated(v=vs.110).aspx) for HttpRequestBase.Unvalidated:

> When implemented in a derived class, provides access to HTTP request
>   values without triggering request validation.

Comment: This was exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 2):

**EDIT:** The commentors are right: AllowHtml is only valid on a model property. I didn't read the question carefully enough but I don't know, why `ValidateInput` shouldn't work.

As far as I know there are 2 possibilities on controllers:

```
[HttpPost]
[AllowHtml]
public void YourMethod(SomeModelType model)
{
}
```

or

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateInput(false)]
public void YourMethod(SomeModelType model)
{
}
```

or a combination of both.

Comment: I am not using a model.  I am just grabbing the httppost request form values.  I can't use the AllowHtml attribute.  I don't control what the sender is sending.

Comment: Is your first example correct? I think the `[AllowHtml]`attribute is only for properties.

Comment: AllowHtml is for the property of a model.  i am not using a model at all which is my problem.  otherwise the allowhtml would work for me.

Comment: `[ValidateInput(false)]` is an action level attribute.. did you try adding this to your ActionResult and see if it worked?