# A potentially dangerous Request.Form value was detected from the client in asp mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, rich-text-editor

I'm using Rich Editor

It shows me this error

Return Null `t.FullText = HttpContext.Request["Editor1"];`

[image: Pic]

View :

```
<div class="name">
    <label id="lbl-full-text">FullText : </label>
  @* @Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.FullText)*@
    <div name="FullText" style="margin-right: 109px;    margin-top: -34px;">
        @Html.Raw(ViewBag.Editor)
    </div>
</div>
```

Controller :

```
[HttpPost, ValidateInput(false)]
public ActionResult CreateNews(Tbl_News t, HttpPostedFileBase pic, int Category = 0)
{
    string content = Request.Unvalidated["Editor1"];
    .
    .
    .
    t.FullText = HttpContext.Request["Editor1"];

}
```

MetaData :

```
[AllowHtml]
public string FullText { get; set; }
```

How can I resolve this ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [A potentially dangerous Request.Form value was detected from the client](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/81991/a-potentially-dangerous-request-form-value-was-detected-from-the-client)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Allow User to input HTML in ASP.NET MVC - ValidateInput or AllowHtml](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3621272/allow-user-to-input-html-in-asp-net-mvc-validateinput-or-allowhtml)

Comment: No . i do this step , but its not work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Finally made this work by intercepting the edited value in jQuery before AJAX posting and escape the value like:

```
$("#Textareaeditor").val(escape(-get value from editor-);
```

Then, serverside you just do:

```
model.property = URI.unEscapeDataString(model.property).
```

This works for md when nothing else did and I did not want to set `requestValidationMode=2.0`.

Answer (score 1):

use `System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.Unvalidated.Form["Editor1"]` disabling the input validation for the whole page or all pages is a bad idea!

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways to handle this.  Not all in my opinion are the best approach.

Here is probably the worst

Shotgun approach

```
<httpRuntime requestValidationMode="2.0"/>
```

Slightly better in that you turn it off on a particular page

```
<configuration>
        <system.web>
            <pages validateRequest="false" />
        </system.web>
</configuration>
```

Here you can turn it off for a particular section of your site

```
<configuration>
...
<location path="MyFolder/.aspx">
<system.web>
<pages validateRequest="false" />
<httpRuntime requestValidationMode="2.0" />
</system.web>
</location>
...
</configuration>
```

Another approach if you are using mvc is to add the validate input attribute to your action:

```
[ValidateInput(false)]
```

It's been a while since I've had to do these in any of the sites I've created but I think they still work.