# Server returns Internal Server Error / Dangerous Request.Form value

Tags: javascript, ajax, asp.net-mvc

MVC project, been around a long time, massive monolith.  I hope I'm missing something here.

I've a form which gets submitted over ajax.  It gets to the server, gets stored away, and I go to return an object to the client (basically status & a destination URL).

If there's anything in the form inputs containing illegal characters (html-ish) then it gives me the error about fearful data.

- I've tried putting `[AllowHtml]` on every single text field of the view model (won't be long-term).
- I've added `[ValidateInput(false)]` on the controller method
- Removed all of the alerts (since it *is* saving the data).

The stupid thing is that it saves the data.  The "dangerous" data makes it to the server and database and back out to the controller method.  I can't seem to catch this, - I've debugged it to where I ship it from the controller, and then in-browser I get the error.

```
var form = $(this).parents('form:first').serializeObject();

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: '@Url.Action("EditAjax", "Item", new {area = "ProjectSupport"})',
    dataType: "json",
    data: form,
    ignoreErrors: true,
    success: function(result) {
    var formData = new FormData($('#editItem')[0]);
    if (result.Errors) {
        //alert(result.Errors);
        $('form').find('a.submit,#saveFormButton1,#saveFormButton2').removeClass('btn-inverse').addClass('btn-primary');
        submitted = false;
    } else {
        formData.append("supportObjectTypeName", result.SupportObjectTypeName);
        formData.append("supportObjectLocalizedID", result.SupportObjectLocalizedID);

        url = result.Url;

        $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: '@Url.Action("UploadAttachments", "Item", new {area = "ProjectSupport"})',
        dataType: "json",
        mimeType: "multipart/form-data",
        contentType: false,
        cache: false,
        processData: false,
        data: formData,
        ignoreErrors: true,
        success: function() {
            window.location.href = url;
        },
        error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
            //alert(thrownError);
            //$('form').find('a.submit,#saveFormButton1,#saveFormButton2').removeClass('btn-inverse').addClass('btn-primary');
            //submitted = false;
            window.location.href = url;
        }
        });
    }
    },
    error: function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
    alert(thrownError);
    alert(xhr.responseText);
    var fullErrorText = [];
    $.each(xhr.responseJSON, function() {
        fullErrorText.push(this.errors.join());
    });
    alert(fullErrorText.join());
    $('form').find('a.submit,#saveFormButton1,#saveFormButton2').removeClass('btn-inverse').addClass('btn-primary');
    submitted = false;
    }
});
```

I've used AllowHtml previously and it worked just fine - slap it onto the model and you're good.  I've just spent a few hours on this issue, though, and I hope somebody out there's brighter than me on this (I'm certain).

Any thoughts, please?

TLDR:

- I've tried putting `[AllowHtml]` on every single text field of the view model.
- I've added `[ValidateInput(false)]` on the controller method (also built a custom filter, just ... grasping at straws).
- Removed all of the alerts (since it *is* saving the data).
- Tried `Request.Unvalidated` as per @queeny's suggestion.

Thoughts:

- Namespaces have changed their defaults or something, 'cause things which previously compiled have been moaning about name conflicts.
- EF has had some issues, but probably the naming issue was the most severe.
- Got the usual "I've left something in cache and couldn't be bothered to fix it" message, interrupting the build.
- CDN had a different URL between debug & prod, with no transformation of `web.config` for that.
- There's no way I'd do a package update (well, I did, but it was brutal).
- There's also a change in compiler (a version 1.x to 4.x).
- I've played with the various attributes, but no joy there.

I think that it was most likely dealing with the namespace issues that let me get through. If I'm picking my superstition of the day.

Comment: Could [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33890271/21972629) answer help? That question has a couple of old but promising leads.

Comment: Thank you, @jQueeny ! I will have a look on Monday or Tuesday but there are some promising responses in there. I have tried the allow HTML ones and basically what is familiar. That question, though, has what likes poke a different solution. This answer looks interesting: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50796666/6850

Comment: Hey, @jQueeny - please format this as an answer & I'll accept your comment as the answer.

Comment: Did you get it fixed then?

Comment: Nope, no fix. I knew the project and restarted from fresh. I imported all of the views and models and all of that. I'm hoping that I can get it to move past the entity framework issues. It's a real pain, doing that kind of rebuild. Ugh!

Comment: Good luck with it. I've built monoliths with Laravel recently and I've got nothing but praise for the framework. Reminds me of Ruby on Rails but better. If it's ever an option to port this to another MVC then definitely look at Laravel.

Answer (score 0):

You could try the `Request.Unvalidated` method as metnioned in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33890271/21972629) answer.

Comment: I will give that a shot.  I ended up creating a whole new MVC site, copying over all of the area contents, recreated all of the EF models, and am now working my way through all of the errors in the EF models.

Comment: @DavidT.Macknet Pfft! That sounds like a lot of work. Post if you ever resolve it.

Comment: I've got until the 17th!  I'm currently getting an error on install-package, seems to be about the compiler.  Part of my issues have been changing paths - I didn't nest them properly & so all of my package paths are messed up.  Meh.  Still not solved.  Today has been a day of bug-seeking.  ugh.

Comment: Made it through the errors, which were mostly to do with something entity framework messed with. I think it's something to do with nesting, but also to do with EF keeping multiple versions of files, so adding some mashed the file reference in the project file. Pulling the errors out into notepad++ and sanitizing it and deduplication and it was easier to find. Not 'easy' to deal with, though. I've spent 2.5 days on this fix & now have to test a new feature (yes, I wrote this thing 10 years ago, so I get to add a feature to the product of 5 years of 95% coding time)